# On device manager it says have 4 of the same 2.40 ghz processors so do i have 9.40 ghz

Tags: cpu

When I go to device manager to check my processor speed there are 4 the same exact processors shown is this a quad core and does the speed add up?

Comment: No and Yes. The issue is that you are measuring in Hertz (cycles/seconds), and all components of the system experience time universally, so no, you don't have 9.40GHz, but you can do approximately the processing a single core 9.4GHz chip could do. Hertz doesn't measure processing power, but the way the system perceives time, and the amount of work that can be done in a given measure of it. if you could measure in FLOPS or another processing-centric metric, then the relationship would be more clear to you.

Comment: I like the car example by Aganju. That's exactly it.

Comment: and 4 x 2.4 is *9.6*, not 9.4. Not that it matters here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.   Your CPU is 2.4GHz.  However, your CPU has multiple cores, and/or a feature called HyperThreading.  These features involve making a single CPU act rather similar to multiple CPUs, or at least multiple partial CPUs.

The "2.4GHz" is your speed, and is a measurement of how many "clock cycles" you have.  If you have a quad-core system, that does not mean that you get 9.40 million clock cycles per second.  However, it does mean that your CPU may be capable of doing more work with each clock cycle.  The effect is that more work gets done within a single clock cycle, and the resulting effect might be similar to having 9.40GHz worth of speed.  Whether you get that speed boost, or not, largely depends on just what kind of software you are using, and how well the software's parallelization implementation is able to utilize CPU features like multi-core CPUs and/or Hyperthreading.

Windows Task Manager is well-known for showing multiple CPU cores as if they were actually different complete CPUs.  However, these individual cores are not actually capable of doing everything that an individual CPU can do, so it is not the same thing.

That's my answer to the question's title, and the question of "does the speed add up"?  (In summary, the answer is: it depends.  For some software, the effect is like adding up the speed, but for other software, it is not.)

As for your question, "is this a quad core", I would guess it is either a quad core without hyperthreading (which often has the effect of appearing to double the number of CPU cores), or a dual core with hyperthreading enabled.  I couldn't tell you which you have, based just on the information that you have provided so far.  (However, some software could tell you that.  Check into CPUID if you like.  Or, maybe just see if your BIOS Setup program provides answers, like showing that the Hyperthreading option is currently enabled.)

Answer (score 1):

No. Simply said, if you buy four cars, you still can't go 360 mph.

Comment: no, but if you and your wife race, the distance you cover aggregately will certainly be 2x distanced the car can travel at top speed.

Comment: @FrankThomas Right, but still you can't describe four cars going 90 miles per hour as anything going 360 miles per hour, which is what the OP is asking about. Clock speeds don't add.